# parser =3D syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
import sys

from cclib.parser import ccopen

from cclib.bridge import makeopenbabel

import openbabel as ob


parser =3D ccopen(sys.argv[1])
data =3D parser.parse()

distort =3D data.atomcoords[0] - data.vibdisps[0]

obmol =3D makeopenbabel(distort, data.atomnos)

obconv =3D ob.OBConversion()

ok =3D obconv.SetOutFormat("XYZ")

obconv.WriteFile(obmol, "distorted.xyz")`
```

This simple python script gives syntax error like following

```
"test.py", line 7
>    parser = 3D ccopen(sys.argv[1])
>              ^
>SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
```

can anyone help to sort this out. Thanks

Comment: Why are you inserting random `3D`s everywhere?

Comment: Looks like copy/paste encoding error. Fix the syntax.

Comment: Looks like epic copy paste fail indeed

Answer (score 4):

This looks like [quoted-printable encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable), which is used in email. Your Python source code should not be quoted-printable encoded, so you need to decode this either manually, by getting the source again without the encoding, or by using [a decoder](http://www.convertstring.com/EncodeDecode/QuotedPrintableDecode).

As you can see from the [example on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable#Example), `=3D` decodes to `=`. You can also verify this by evaluating `chr(int('3D', 16))` in Python, which interprets `3D` as a hexadecimal value (base 16), and finds the ASCII character represented by that number.

Answer (score -2):

Although this will fix the code. I will not be surprised if you get errors for lack of libraries.

```
import sys
from cclib.parser import ccopen
from cclib.bridge import makeopenbabel
import openbabel as ob


parser = ccopen(sys.argv[1])
data = parser.parse()
distort = data.atomcoords[0] - data.vibdisps[0]
obmol = makeopenbabel(distort, data.atomnos)
obconv = ob.OBConversion()
ok = obconv.SetOutFormat("XYZ")
obconv.WriteFile(obmol, "distorted.xyz")`
```

Comment: -1: posting the corrected source code w/o telling what the problem was (or trying to understand where the `=3d`s came from) won't help the general audience at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Kay. I think code was copied out of a mail. So =3d seems like artifact of that

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions, but removal of 3D returns with the following error  "File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    parser = ccopen(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The script is expecting a command-line argument. A filename to be precise.